# Post answer as guest - strange Markdown help toolbar behaviour when focused on name/email fields

Tags: bug

If you scroll down any question, you will see "**Your Answer**" form, if you are not logged in to SO, this form looks like this:
[image]

There is strange UI behaviour in "**Post as a guest**" section: when you try focus on *Name* or *Email* field first, it also opens "*Markdown Editing Help*" toolbar in "*Your Answer*" textarea:

[image]

*Edit:* if textarea focused first, this toolbar also appears, and it is understandable - user can input Markdown in the textarea.

But if Name/Email clicked first, Markdown help toolbar is not relevant, and probably should not appear.

Comment: Note that this bar expands too if you click the answer body, and it doesn't expand again if it has already expanded once, so if the user first types an answer and then enters his name/e-mail this doesn't happen. I would call this _strange_, but _bug_ is a bit strong.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth edited question